# Lubuntu 18.04 screensaver lock not working

Tags: lubuntu, screensaver, lock

I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 (or 10, don't recall). In the last couple of days, my screensaver lock has stopped working. It was working fine a few days ago. My screensaver would kick in and in order to get back to the UI, I had to enter my PW. I noticed that in the screensaver configuration, the "Lock screen after" option was not checked. I have rechecked it but it still is not working. My screensaver starts and when I press a key, the UI comes back without having to enter my password. Is there some other setting that needs to be set?

I found another post from someone talking about the same thing but for Xubuntu. In there it said to run the following command (env | grep -i manager) and post the results. Not sure if this will help with Lubuntu but here are the results from running it:

XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session1

Comment: Re. "I'm using Lubuntu 18.04 (or 10, don't recall)", run `lsb_release -d` and edit your question accordingly. There's a vast difference between 18.04 and 18.10.

Comment: 18.04 uses LXDE, 18.10 uses LXQt so are very different. The editor in 18.04 is leafpad, 18.10 has featherpad as an example showing apps on each are different as DK Bose stated (as 18.04 apps used GTK+ & 18.10 use Qt)   There is a *huge* difference between Lubuntu 18.04 & 18.10 unless excluding GUI or name Lubuntu (screensaver is gui related!).   Your grep imply to me you're running 18.04 (LXDE) but we can't help unless we know.